# How to solve an equation with 6 degree polynomial?

Tags: polynomials, roots

Does anyone have an idea to solve the following equation if it is possible? It's the best to get analytic solution, but if you can help me to show when equation has all real root with certain conditions of parameters, it is also alright. 
Variable is $\Omega$, and parameters are $M_1 >0$ and $r >0, r \neq 1$.
I am trying to find when it has all real roots.

$f(\Omega)=(r-1)\Omega^6 - (r+1) \Omega^5 - \frac{(r-1)}{4} \Omega^4 + \left(\frac{(r+1)}{2}+ \frac{4}{M_1^2}\right)\Omega^3 -\frac{(r-1)}{16} \Omega^2 + \left(\frac{1}{M_1^2}- \frac{r+1}{16}\right)\Omega + \frac{(r-1)}{64}=0.$

Thank you very much for any help!

Comment: If $r=1$ then $f$ is a quintic, so it has at most $5$ real roots.

Comment: Thank you very much! In the case of r = 1, I also have done.

Comment: Also, it seems at a glance that the result of Descartes' rule of signs depends on whether $r>1$ or $r<1$, and the sign of $\tfrac{1}{M_1^2}-\tfrac{r+1}{16}$.

Comment: Yes, it depends on $r>1$ or $r<1$, but both of cases showed it has at least 4 real roots

Comment: Also, does Descartes' rule of signs on only give an upper bound on the number of real roots? If $r<1$ I find *at most* two positive real roots, and *at most* four negative real roots.

Comment: Also, with $r=M_1=1$ I get only three real roots.

Comment: You are right! At $r<1$, $f(\Omega)$ changes sign two times, $f(-\Omega)$ changes sign four times. Then it has either two or $(6-2)=4$ real positive, and either four or $(6-4)=2$ real negative roots. Therefore, it has at least $2+2 =4$ real roots. In the case of $r=1$ are exception, therefore we may consider $r \neq 1$

Comment: No; $f(\Omega)$ changes sign twice, so it has either $2$ or $0$ positive roots, and $f(-\Omega)$ changes sign four times, so it has either $4$, $2$ or $0$ negative roots.

Comment: As an aside, for $r\neq1$ this is equivalent to determining the number of real roots of
$$\frac{64f(\tfrac x2)}{r-1}=x^6-32tx^5-x^4+32(s+t)x^3-x^2+32(s-t)x+4,$$
where $t:=\frac{1}{16}+\tfrac{1}{8(r-1)}$ and $s=\tfrac{1}{M_1^2}$, so $t\notin[-\tfrac{127}{128},\tfrac{1}{16}]$ and $s>0$, and $t$ is negative if and only if $r<1$.

Comment: Plugging in $r=0.1$ and $M_1=0.001$ yields only two real roots. Some more random values with $r<1$ seem to suggest that $f$ has only two real roots for most values of $M_1>0$ and $0<r<1$.

Comment: Ah yes, you are right! But I don't know how why I solve it numerically by mathematica. It always show at least four root with $r \neq 1$. I wish I can find the formulation of solution. But I want to know when it has all real roots.

Comment: Correction; in my comment above the range for $t$ should be $t\notin[-\tfrac{1}{16},\tfrac{1}{16}]$.

Comment: Can you explain a little more? How did you get the condition of $M_1^2$ and the range of $t$? I am not clear.

Comment: If $s=\tfrac{1}{M_1^2}$ then $M_1>0$ implies precisely that $s>0$. Similarly if $r>0$ then if $r<1$ it follows that $t<-\tfrac{1}{16}$ and if $r>1$ then $t>\tfrac{1}{16}$.

Comment: Ah I see. I made mistake that $t$ belongs to $[-\frac{1}{16},\frac{1}{16}]$. And how about the condition of $M_1^2$, I saw your comment before that $M_1^2 < ...$ has no real root at all

Comment: I have posted an answer to give a few more details.

Answer (score 1):

The following is a summary and expansion of some of my comments above, and by no means a complete answer to the question.

---

If $r<1$ then by Descartes' rule of signs $f$ has either $2$ or $0$ positive real roots, and either $4$, $2$ or $0$ negative real roots, and  clearly $\Omega=0$ is not a root. It is not true in general that $f$ has at least $4$ roots.

If $r\neq1$ then setting $t:=\frac{1}{16}+\tfrac{1}{8(r-1)}$ and $s=\tfrac{1}{M_1^2}$ we might as well find the roots of 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\tfrac{f(x)}{r-1}&=&x^6-\left(1+\tfrac{2}{r-1}\right)x^5-\tfrac14x^4
+\left(\tfrac12+\tfrac{1}{r-1}+\tfrac{4}{M_1^2}\right)x^3-\tfrac{1}{16}x^2 + \left(\tfrac{1}{M_1^2}-\tfrac{1}{16}-\tfrac{1}{8(r-1)}\right)x+\tfrac{1}{16}\\
&=&x^6-16tx^5-\tfrac14x^4+(8t+4s)x^3-\tfrac{1}{16}x^2+(s-t)x+\tfrac{1}{16},
\end{eqnarray*}
with the conditions that $s>0$ and $t\notin[-\tfrac{1}{16},\tfrac{1}{16}]$, or even the nicer looking
$$\frac{64f(\tfrac x2)}{r-1}=x^6-32tx^5-x^4+32(s+2t)x^3-x^2+32(s-t)x+4.$$
Then if $t<0$ and $s>-t$ then most coefficients are positive; setting the above equal to $0$ yields
$$x^6+32(-t)x^5+32(s+2t)x^3+32(s+(-t))x+4=x^4+x^2,$$
where the terms are sorted left and right so that all coefficients are positive. But it is not hard to check that for all real $x$ we have
$$x^6+4>x^4+x^2,$$
so $f$ has no positive real roots if $t<0$ and $s>-t$, or equivalently $r<1$ and
$$\frac{1}{M_1^2}>-\left(\frac{1}{16}+\frac{1}{8(r-1)}\right),$$
which is in turn equivalent to $M_1^2>16\frac{1-r}{1+r}$.

Similarly, if $t>0$ and $s<t$ then all coefficients in the equation
$$(-x)^6+32t(-x)^5+32(s-t)(-x)+4=(-x)^4+32(s+2t)(-x)^3+(-x)^2,$$
are positive. If $c<1.94316$ then for all real $x$ we have
$$x^6+4>x^4+cx^3+x^2,$$
so if $32(s+2t)<1.94316$ then the above has no real solutions, so $f$ has no negative real roots. In particular, by Descartes' rule of signs it has at most $2$ real roots.

**EDIT:** The inequality $32(s+2t)<1.94316$ is not satisfied as $t>0$ implies $t>\tfrac{1}{16}$. This shows that $f$ has at least two negative real roots if $r>1$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your post! It will help me a lot. I am trying to understand and check again your calculation.

Comment: I have checked the coefficient of $x^3$ in equation $f(\frac{x}{2})$ has a small mistake. I think it should be $32(2 t + s)$